# How to get captured grouping using regex and javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get pieces of a youtube embed link. I am not familiar with how group capturing works in javascript.

This is what I have

```
<Script>
var str = "<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/JxE1oj06xH8\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

var re = /(?:<iframe)(\swidth=\"\d+\")|(\sheight=\"\d+\")|(\ssrc=\"(?:http:)?(//)?www\.youtube\.com/embed/\w+\"?)(.+></iframe>)/g;

var array = str.match(re);

document.write(array[0]);
</script>
```

I was expecting the result to be the data captured by this

```
(\swidth=\"\d+\")
```

For ever group, I want to be able to get the data in the parenthesis (that's 4 groups total.) 
How do I go about getting the data in the groups?

Comment: There is an error in your regexp: **SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical**

Comment: Ok, found the problem with the regexp: you must escape `/` or it used as the end of the regexp: `var re = /(?:<iframe)(\swidth=\"\d+\")|(\sheight=\"\d+\")|(\ssrc=\"(?:http:)?(\/\/)?www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/\w+\"?)(.+><\/iframe>)/g;`

Comment: For goodness sakes.  Use single quotes around the outside of your string and then you don't have to escape double quotes inside the string - makes it twice as readable.  AND, you don't have to escape quotes at all in a `/regular expression/` definition.  Everything will be a LOT easier to read if you get rid of all that extra escaping.

Comment: Are you sure you want `' width="420"'` instead of `'420'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.match() returns as array of the captured brackets. To make things a little easier to look at, I replaced the \" with single ', and then parsed the string.

Obviously a simpler solution would be to start with single quotes around your string, but I gotta work with what ya give me.

```
var str = "<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/JxE1oj06xH8\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

str = str.replace(/\"/g, "'");

var re = /width='(\d+)' height='(\d+)' src='\/\/(www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/\w+)' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen><\/iframe>/;

var array = str.match(re);

console.log(array);
```

Depending how specific you can be, and what other values you might want to capture you should be able to adapt this. With regex I'd say you want to be as specific as you KNOW you can be.

[This was a great little tutorial when I first learnt regex for JS.](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: This worked, I think the double quotes were confusing me. I had to double quote originally because that is how youtube displays its embed links by default.